# memory leak delete linked list node

Tags: c++11, linked-list

Newbie question.  Suppose I have a C++11 linked list implementation with

```
template <typename X> struct Node {
   X value;
   Node* next;

   Node(X x) {
      this->value = x;
      this->next = nullptr;
   }
};
```

and later in the code I create a pointer variable

```
X x = something;
Node<X>* node = new Node(x);
```

and still later I do

```
delete node;
```

Is the x stored within node destructed when this statement is executed?

You may tell me I should use std::list instead of writing my own, but right 
now I'm just trying to educate myself on pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide a custom desctructor the compiler will generate the default one for you, which (by default) call destructors on its elements.

Now, the answer to your question really depends on what your `x` is :) If it is an object that has a destructor (like `std::string`) - it will be properly destroyed. But if it is a "naked pointer" (like `int *`) - it will **not** get destroyed and will cause a memory leak.

**N.B.** You create your `x` on a stack so I really-really-really hope that `X` provides proper copy semantics, otherwise you may end up with an invalid object stored in your node!

Comment: To make this code more robust, is there a way in C++ of telling if a template typename is a pointer, so that I can call delete on x?  Any other suggestions for making this more robust?